# How to split a string in JSP or JAVA?

Tags: java, string, jsp, split

{"Uid":"049237d2544280"

I have this string . i just want 049237d2544280 value in a variable. I just want value that is in double quotes.

I uses this code in jsp

```
List<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
           Matcher match = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+|[a-z]+|[A-Z]+").matcher(TagID);
          while (match.find()) 
           {

              output.add(match.group());
           }

          out.println(output);
```

But the ouput was like this
 [U, id, 049237, d, 2544280]

Comment: if it's json data, using a json library might be a better choice

Comment: No this not json object. Basically this is a text file where i have this data. i am reading this text file through my jsp page. Text file contain {"Uid":"049237d2544280","ReadOnly":false,"DataLength":15,"CanMakeReadOnly":true,"Formatted":true,"Records":[{"Title":null,"LanguageCode":5,"EncodingType":0,"Url":"https://www.google.com","RecordType":"Website"}],"TagTech":"NTAG213","MaxDataLength":142,"Exception":null}. I just want UID in a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

Matcher match = Pattern.compile("[0-9a-z0-9]{14}+").matcher(TagID);

Comment: Thanks it showing like this. [049237d2544280]  but how can i remove this square bracket i want to use this string to query database and fetch the data